# CountdownTimer isn't working

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I need a CountDownTimer that saves it's remaining time after the application closes as well. I have this code, and I'm not really sure if my HH:DD format is bad or the SharedPreferences aren't working well. Also, If someone may modify this code to work with seconds too, I will be very thankful.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


   new CountDownTimer(86400000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long elapsed) {

             if(elapsed/3600>=10&&(elapsed/60000)/24>=10)           
                    time.setText(elapsed/3600000+":"+(elapsed/60000)/24);
                    else 
                        if(elapsed/60000>=10&&(elapsed/60000)/24<10)
                        time.setText(elapsed/36000+":"+"0"+elapsed/60000);               
                        else if(elapsed/60000<10&&(elapsed/60000)/24>10)
                            time.setText("0"+elapsed/36000+":"+elapsed/60000);      
                            if(elapsed/60000<10&&(elapsed/60000)/24<10)
                            time.setText("0"+elapsed/36000+":"+"0"+elapsed/60000);  

                              elapsed = prefs.getLong("TIME", 86400000);
                              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                              editor.putLong("TIME",elapsed);
                              editor.commit(); 
         }
         public void onFinish() {

         }
      }.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm never tried it but in ANDengine library for 2d games there is an example of a chronometer, so you maybe you can look at it!! it comes with seconds and milliseconds. [here](http://www.andengine.org/) you will find more information about the library.

Comment: search for ANDengine example there you will find all the  examples of the ANDengine library, They are the project page